# Jquery Attr Returns Undefined

Tags: jquery, undefined, attr

Jquery

Im creating div and adding attr in loop. And in other function i need to access it but it returns `undefined` and `.data("color",value)`(set) and `.data("color")`(get) is not working for me is there any diffirent way for getting or setting for custom attribute

```
$("#"+i+"-"+j).attr("data-color",a);
```

---

```
var bColor = $("#"+newX+"-"+j).attr("data-color");

console.log(bColor);
```

Comment: And you're sure it's the same element ?

Comment: have you verified that `i === newX`  (*and `j` hasn't changed its value between the two calls ?*)

Comment: yes im getting it from loop im sure these are same element checked in console for being sure...

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce this issue. There are numerous reasons this might occur

Comment: Can you post an executable snippet that demonstrates the problem? As long as the values match there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the code given, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/vdv3omkj/

Comment: Please create an  MCVE (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add it to your question. You will get faster, better help from the community that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use .attr, to read and set data values, but use .data() by jQuery. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: this won't resolve the issue although it is the preferred way to get and set `data-` attributes